# Exponential Growth and Decay Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Annual sales for a clothing store are $270,000 and are increasing at a rate of 7% per year. Find out how much money is made in 3 years. Use the formula y=a(1+r)^t.

Comment: Why is this tagged algebraic geometry?

Comment: I propose to close this too elementary question : the OP is unable to apply an elementary formula.

Comment: What have you tried?  You are given a formula and values for the variables.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Such problems were what led to Grothendieck K-theory.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_K-theory  ummmm. Say it out loud.

Comment: You have a formula, $a=270000$, $r=0.07$, $t=3$

Comment: @WillJagy I feel like there is a clever joke here, but I am missing it. Elaborate?

Comment: @JeanMarie Elementary problems are a poor reason to close, IMO. Lack of effort, however, is a great one.

Comment: @TheCount well, say the question title out loud, then say my sentence out loud.

Comment: @WillJagy Holy crap I can't believe I missed that the first time. That's actually amazing.

Comment: @WillJagy My insufficient level in English has prevented me to understand something that must be a joke. May I ask you to give me a supplementary hint (I know, it is distateful to explain jokes or puns...) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it is entirely about pronunciation, especially the most common way these things are said in America. The phrase "growth and decay" has a  similar sound to "Grothendieck K." It is certainly possible that the usual French pronunciation of Grothendieck does not allow for this pun.

Comment: Grothendieck K would be pronounced Gr-oh-th-en-deek-kay.  This is an exponential word problem about .....

Comment: @Will Nagy Thanks, Will. I appreciate. Indeed, the "th" is pronounced "t" in French...

Answer (score 1):

As Alex points out in the comment, $a=\$270,000$, $r=0.07$, and $t=3$.Putting that into the formula $y=a(1+r)^t$, we arrive at the following:
$$
y=a(1+r)^t\\
y=\$270,000(1+0.07)^3\\
y=\$270,000(1.07)^3\\
y=\$270,000*1.225\\
y=\$330,761.61
$$

Comment: I don't think the question should have been answered.